# rc.local not being run on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, rc.local

I have an iptables script I want to run at boot.
I created /etc/rc.d/rc.local file with CHMOD 755 permissions which have worked on previous operating systems.
Root owns the file.
I also have #!/bin/bash as the first line.
I have also tried #!/bin/sh
I have also added a 5 second sleep thinking maybe something needs to finish.
I have temporarily disabled selinux to eliminate that as a cause.
The rc.local file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash  
sleep 5  
/usr/local/sbin/miniptables
```

The miniptables file is also owned by root, chmod 755, starts with #!/bin/bash, contains some iptables commands, and has worked on hundreds of servers.
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to avoid home-grown firewall scripts, if you can, and just use firewalld.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Just create `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` and make it executable. **That's all.**

I have no idea why so many articles and blogs mentions the unnecessary and incorrect step of enabling `rc-local` service unit. It won't even work as the default `rc.local` file does not have `WantedBy` statement on purpose, because systemd carries so called [generator](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/rc-local-generator/rc-local-generator.c) that checks if such file exists and it is executable it automatically generates the mentioned `rc-local.service`. There is no need to enable it manually, in fact, you cannot do that until systemd boots and generates it or you run the generator manually:

```
# systemctl enable --now rc-local
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` file doesn't have execute permissions by default, so set it executable:

```
# chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Also, the file is not run unless the systemd `rc-local` service is enabled, but it is disabled by default. So you need to enable (and start) it:

```
# systemctl start rc-local
# systemctl enable rc-local
```

For systemd systems, it is usually better to [write your own systemd service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd).

Comment: It would be helpful if you offered explanations of what those commands do, instead of encouraging blind copy/paste sysadmin practices.

Comment: unfortunately your suggestion did not work.  I forgot to mention that I checked rc-local service as well.  The execution bit was already set per chmod 755 but I did your command anyway.  Here is the output:  systemctl status rc-local  
...  
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2015-12-28 14:58:17 CST; 1h 0min ago
...  
systemctl is-enabled rc-local  
static  
systemctl enable rc-local  
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
...

Comment: Add "logger test"  call to /etc/rc.local and after reboot check journalctl if test record was added.

Comment: Added logger test and now it is working and I don't know why :( Thanks though